# How to use drawable animation on button press

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

I've tried many of the codes in here, but nothing worked 
and there are simply no tutorials out there how to use a 
drawable animation when I press a button.

But **NOTHING** worked.

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/lostpressd" />
</selector>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/e1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/e2" android:duration="50" />
    and so on
```

and the lostpress in reverse.

Comment: What do you eactly want? Click effect on button pressed?

Comment: As the title says, when a button gets pressed the button drawable animation should play.

Answer (score 0):

i solved your problam:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image2"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image3"
        android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

in your activity :

```
 final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_img);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
            AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
            animationDrawable.setVisible(true, true);
            animationDrawable.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your try. But I don't use a ImageView. And on a Button I get  android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Answer (score 0):

First, create an animation vector drawable. This is a pretty good (simple) tutorial: https://medium.com/@naththeprince/delightful-animations-in-android-d6e9c62a23d3. Next, in your `xml` file, define a normal button, like so:

```
<Button
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_animated_vector_drawable"
  android:id="@+id/example_button"/>
```

and add whatever other properties you want inside the `Button`.

In your code, use this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.example_button);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  // Get the left drawable: (the one you set in the xml file)
  AnimatedVectorDrawable avd =
    (AnimatedVectorDrawable) showPopup.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
  avd.start();
});
```

This worked for me. Hope it works for you as well!